# Como colocar uma cor de fundo em um ShapeDrawable?

Tags: android

Parece ser algo bem simples, mas só estou conseguindo colocar a cor da borda, alguém sabe? Segue o código que estou usando:

```
public void borda(View view) {
    float[] outerR = new float[] {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
    RectF   inset = new RectF(6, 6, 6, 6);
    float[] innerR = new float[] { 12, 12, 0, 0, 12, 12, 0, 0 };
    ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable();
    sd.setShape(new RoundRectShape(outerR, null, null));
    sd.getPaint().setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    sd.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(3f);
    //sd.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    sd.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    view.setBackground(sd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer somente inserir uma cor, esse é o caminho mais curto:

```
ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable();
drawable.getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```